# filtering the output of AWS CLI Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-route53

When I run `aws route53domains list-domains --region us-east-1 --output text --no-cli-pager` the output is a listing of my domains, but it includes additional data I don't want including 'AutoRenew', Expiry' & 'TransferLock'. I'm looking for a simple, flat list of domain names, one per line, with no other info

trying to use --query:

```
aws route53domains list-domains \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --output table \
    --no-cli-pager \
    --query 'DomainName'
```

but I cant find/understand the documentation I'm finding.  I simply want:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
etc
```

Comment: The query language is the inscrutable [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Let you try

```
aws --profile bmd route53 list-hosted-zones --query "HostedZones[*].Name "
```

or

```
aws --profile bmd route53 list-hosted-zones --output text --query "HostedZones[*].Name "
```

if one of these two fit your needs.

Comment: Or `aws route53domains list-domains --query "Domains[*].DomainName" --output text`

Comment: thanks this is working, except the output is a space-separated list vs CRLF separated (if that makes sense) as I want to use the list as the input to a shell script, a CRLF list is needed, but thank you

Comment: I am curious why you cannot add at the end something simple like `| tr " " "\n"`. to achieve that.